# Error NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies

Tags: android, compiler-errors, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I had my program building successfully but then I updated my Android Studio to version 1.0.

First I had this error after the update:

> Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0-rc4.
>   Fix plugin version and re-import project

Then this error that I fixed by replacing runProguard by minifyEnabled:

Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'

And finally this error appeared:

> Error:Class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

I already looked in several places but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know how to solve it? The project was building successfully until the update.

Comment: Try rebuilding your project (Build > Rebuild Project)

Comment: Clean and Rebuild Project didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have the same problem as me, I solve my problem the hard way. The solution I found was create a new project with the same name, copy all the basic files (java, xml and drawable) to the new project and copy the lines I wanted from the manifest. After it builds the Gradle, it builds sucessfully. I think the reason must be about the new arrangement of foulders from the version 1.0

There must be a better way but until then, at least now it works. Thanks to those who tried to help